# firebase rules path containing generated id

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to set up my firebase rules, So I'm trying to sort my messages by time but I failed to represent the path.

## My data:

[image]

## Firebase rules:

```
{  
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "conversations": {
            "messages":{
            ".indexOn": ["time"]
          } 
    }
  }
}
```

## component.ts ( Angular 5) (Angularfire 5.0.0-rc.4)

Until now I'm ordering my message in the client side and I'm trying to find how to do it in the backend side.

```
getMessages(id) {
      this.db.list('/conversations/' + id+ '/messages') 
      //, ref => ref.orderByChild('time')
      .valueChanges()

      .pipe(
        tap(messages => {
          messages.sort(
            (obj1: any, obj2: any) => {
              if (obj1.time > obj2.time) {
                return 1;
              }
              if (obj1.time < obj2.time) {
                return -1;
              }
              return 0;
            }
          )
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        (messages: any) => {
        this.messages = messages;
        console.log("RECUUUUU", messages);

        this.scrollToBottom();
      },
        (error)=>{
          console.log("error getMessages");

        }
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The generated paths are typically represented by `$` variables in rules. For example. Any rule starting with a `$` applies to all unmatched nodes under that location.

So in your case to  index all message for all users on their `time` property:

```
{  
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "conversations": {
      "$uid": {
        "messages":{
          "$messageid": {
            ".indexOn": ["time"]
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The exact `$uid` and `$messageid` are variable names, meaning that you can use their value inside the rules under where the variable is declared (and its value captured when executing that rule).

Comment: I still getting data unsorted by time, they still sorted by messageId :( the front solution that I found is by sorting data in pipe(map ... ), and I'd like to put it in the backend level (firebase)

Comment: Creating an index does not automatically sort items, it merely allows Firebase to do sorting you request on the server instead of in the client. You'll have to do that in your query by calling one of the `orderBy...` methods. If you're having trouble making that work, add the minimal **code** to your question too.

Comment: Your call to the database doesn't specify any ordering. Also note that one of your nodes has the timestamp as a string, while the others have it as a number. That will affect the sort order too.